# Throw error , if duplicate data (not duplicate records) found in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table which contains information about products, I need to check for duplicate records and throw an error. There are two columns ,product key and product value, where product value contains both semi-colon separate and normal values. The sample data is given below. (No constraints )

```
source_id |Product_key | Product_value
-----------------------------------------------------------
     1      xzy         PRODUCT_TAG=SCENT;CODE=123;PRICE=234
     1      xhmr          POWDER
     1      abc           PRODUCT_TAG=COMB;CODE=123;PRICE=234
     1      xhmr          OIL
     1      zrmt          123
```

Now i have to check if any two rows have the same product_key and product_tag value, also if the product_key is xhmr , then product_value should be considered as product_tag value. The query which i have written is given below

```
select source_id, PRODUCT_KEY, rec , (case when  instr(rec,'PRODUCT_TAG')<>0 THEN regexp_substr(TRIM(rec), '[^=]+', 1,2)
ELSE rec
end) as PRODUCT_TAG
from 
(select source_id,PRODUCT_KEY ,regexp_substr(TRIM(PRODUCT_VALUE), '[^;]+', 1,LEVEL) AS rec from products 
 connect by  regexp_substr(TRIM(PRODUCT_VALUE), '[^;]+', 1,LEVEL) is not null
    AND prior source_id = source_id
   AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL) where instr(rec,'PRODUCT_TAG')<>0 or PRODUCT_KEY in('xhmr');
```

Output

```
source_id |Product_key | Product_value
-----------------------------------------------------------
     1      xzy           SCENT
     1      xhmr          POWDER
     1      abc           COMB
     1      xhmr          OIL
```

After this, I am taking a count of all the rows and all the distinct rows . If both counts are not equal, then throwing error.I was wondering , if all this could be done in a concise way.

Comment: distinct rows based on all the fields from the main select ?

Comment: yes @RobertoHernandez

Comment: `AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL` does not make any sense. The result of `sys_guid()` will never be `null`. You can just as well leave that condition out.

Comment: without this i am getting error ....connect by loop in user data@a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might do the following

- Get the main query and put into a with clause
- Then you can operate with it as many times as needed

You could write it like this:

**Update**

```
  with main_query 
    as ( 
    select source_id, PRODUCT_KEY, rec , (case when  instr(rec,'PRODUCT_TAG')<>0 THEN regexp_substr(TRIM(rec), '[^=]+', 1,2)
    ELSE rec
    end) as PRODUCT_TAG
    from 
    (select source_id,PRODUCT_KEY ,regexp_substr(TRIM(PRODUCT_VALUE), '[^;]+', 1,LEVEL) AS rec from products 
     connect by  regexp_substr(TRIM(PRODUCT_VALUE), '[^;]+', 1,LEVEL) is not null
        AND prior source_id = source_id
       AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL) where instr(rec,'PRODUCT_TAG')<>0 or PRODUCT_KEY in('xhmr')
    ) 
    select 
    case when total_value = tot_dist then 'OK' -- whatever you want here
    else 'ERROR' -- whatever you want here
    end as result
    from 
    (  ( select count(*) as total_value  from main_query ) ,
       ( select count(*) as total_dist  from ( select distinct * from main_query ) ) 
    )
```

Example in my case

```
 SQL> desc my_test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 C1                                                 NUMBER
 C2                                                 NUMBER

SQL> select * from my_test ;

        C1         C2
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1          1
         2          2

SQL>  with main_query as ( select c1 , c2 from my_test )
  select a , b
 from
 ( select count(*) as a  from main_query ) ,
 ( select count(*) as b  from ( select distinct * from main_query ) )
 /  2    3    4    5    6

         A          B
---------- ----------
         3          2

 SQL>  with main_query as ( select c1 , c2 from my_test )
  select case when a = b then 'OK' else 'ERROR' end as result
 from
 ( select count(*) as a  from main_query ) ,
 ( select count(*) as b  from ( select distinct * from main_query ) )
/

RESUL
-----
ERROR
```

Comment: count(distinct(*))  shows error, i think to find distinct count for multiple columns , we have to select distinct rows and then count them.

Comment: let me check, I did not build a test case. one minute please ;)

Comment: you are totally right. I had to select the distinct values before to make the count.

Comment: I was missing the distinct ( select count xxx ) in the original answer. Let me know whether it works now

Comment: @AvinashTiwari , can you accept the answer? really appreciated

Comment: I was thinking another way  of implementing this would be , to create a  main_query cursor and then put the result into an associative array,  and index the array by  concat(product_key, product_tag) ??? What do you think about this approach @RobertoHernandez

Comment: using SQL or PL/SQL?

Comment: pl/sql @RobertoHernandez

Comment: I did not know you could use PL/SQL. For sure you will have much more options there, using an array might be an option, but like I said, there you have a lot of options